# iTunes cross-platform IAP subscriptions - how does Netflix do it?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, subscriptions

I'm creating a service which allows users to register on any number of devices (web, Android, Roku, iOS, Apple TV), and then purchase a monthly subscription to watch video content. The subscription provides access to the entire catalog. I have my own subscription management API running on a server which I'd like to leverage as the source of truth so users can purchase a subscription on their iPad, login to the app on Roku, and continue watching where they left off.

Basically, Netflix.

Here are my options as far as I can tell:

1. Auto-renewing subscriptions: this is what Netflix uses today, but Apple doesn't provide an API or any set of webhooks around their payment platform, so I don't know how this option could work. My back-end service will have no idea when Apple automatically renews the subscription each month or if a user cancels their subscriptions.
2. Non-renewing subscriptions: users purchase the subscription inside
   the app though IAP. Once purchase is complete, the app sync’s the
   subscription to my back-end system. The app interfaces with my
   back-end any time an entitlement check is required. When a user’s
   subscription is about to expire, the app must present purchase
   workflow again.
3. Import iTunes reports: won't work because it's not realtime (pull, not push) and doesn't tell me anything about cancelled subscriptions. I can only generate reports of new subscribers.
4. Receipt validation & push receipts to my service: won't work because it depends on the user actually using my app. Users could theoretically subscribe in my app, switch to Roku, and never open it again.
5. Skip IAP altogether and require users to subscribe via web.

Am I missing something? I'm really curious how Netflix is pulling this off.

Comment: Unless I'm forgetting something, I don't think Netflix uses the Apple In-App Purchase subscription system at all.  I think you just buy your subscription through Netflix directly, and they track your account status, etc.  Their app just checks with the server and their own internal tracking to see if your account is still active.  If I was trying to do this, I'd just PayPal subscriptions or something similar, and bypass platform-specific APIs completely.  Plus, you wouldn't have to give Apple (or Google, etc) a cut of each subscription.

Comment: As of last month, Netflix allows users to subscribe via their iDevices and they use IAP (as per Apple's guidelines; they don't allow in-app payments through any other system)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this is old, but Apple recently introduced [Status Update Notifactions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW13) which accomplishes what the OP asked for via webhooks:

1. Configure Apple to send notifications to your specified endpoint. ([Apple's small guide](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev0067a330b))
2. Handle the JSON object that's sent via HTTP POST from the App Store and validate latest receipt.
3. Update/save data to your database.
4. Respond with a `200` status code to report a success.

You'll be able to handle the following notification types: `INITIAL_BUY`, `CANCEL`, `RENEWAL`, `INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL`, `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREFERENCE`

The documentation in the link above explains implementation and types in more detail.

Comment: I would like to point out that there have been noted problems (check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049771/never-get-renewal-notification-type-on-apple-statusupdatenotification) and [this Apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93749)) with full implementations of these notifications.

Answer (score 22):

For the initial subscription purchase:

1. User initiates a purchase on the iDevice
2. Device contacts Apple, Apple issues a receipt and sends it back to the device
3. The device sends the receipt to my server
4. The server validates that the receipt is legit through Apple's receipt validation API
5. Once the receipt is validated, the server stores it in my DB
6. The server responds to the app saying it's all good

To keep the server in sync with the iTunes subscription:

1. Setup a cron job to retrieve expiring receipts from the DB on a daily basis or something
2. Validate each receipt with Apple
3. Apple will respond with an updated version of the receipt that contains details regarding whether or not the subscription was canceled/renewed/etc.
4. Server replaces the original receipt with this updated version in the DB

Now if someone logs into their account on a Roku or some other device, the subscription can be honored because my DB is the source of truth.

Comment: you aren't saving over the original binary64 receipt that you are verifying that stays the same and can be reused later in your answer you are talking about saving what we traditionally view as receipt and using that to update corresponding data points around subscription etc. Answer makes it seem like its the same thing.

Comment: *4.Server replaces the original receipt with this updated version in the DB* - This is not really required, the original receipt always gives you the latest info. No need to replace it with any other future receipts.

Comment: And how do you handle if another user logs in on this device with a new account? You would register that this new user has a valid receipt and subscription, although they didn't pay anything. They would now login on to their device and your DB would allow the subscription.