# How to prevent same Apple ID usage for multiple users' in app purchases

Tags: ios, xamarin, in-app-purchase, subscription, apple-id

I am developing cross-platform mobile app and using [InAppBiling Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin) for my app's in app purchase feature but I have a question about below scenario on iOS:

*Scenario*:

- User A gets the subscription with his app credentials and his Apple ID.
- User B uses User A's device and login with User B app credentials but uses User A's Apple ID to buy a subscription.

Currently, it allows that User B to purchase this item but it says that there is a subscription with this user and asks for a permission to modify this subscription.

My question is how to prevent User B to modify User A's subscription? I could not find any solution before the receipt creation. I do not want to allow User B that modifies User A's subscription. I want to inform User B about using different Apple ID to continue to buy a subscription.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32971193/9865234)

You have to have backend that is your source of truth about subscriptions.

The situation that you have provided would look like this:

1. User A gets the subscription with his app credentials and his Apple ID.
2. You send receipt to your backend to validate it as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1)
3. Your server stores information about subscription and link it with user A
4. User B uses User A's device and login with User B app credentials but uses User A's Apple ID to buy a subscription.
5. You send that receipt to your backend as in point 2
6. Your backend responds that this subscription is already connected with user A

Edit:

As mentioned in [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/persisting_a_purchase):

> Send a copy of the receipt to your server along with some kind of
> credentials or identifier so you can keep track of which receipts
> belong to a particular user. For example, let users identify
> themselves to your server with an email or user name, plus a password.

Comment: So, there is no way to prevent this before going to backend right? I am currently doing backend solution but I wanted to prevent user before going to backend.

Comment: @BasakSerit Yes, this is the only way. I have extended the answer with a link to the apple docs mentioning this solution

Comment: Okay, I am currently checking it in the backend, but user A’s subscription is changing with user B’s request and User A charging with this modified subscription. Because there is a valid, updated receipt and this is a problem.

Comment: @BasakSerit you should compare [transaction id](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW13)

Comment: @MichalGorzalczany, but User B able to update plan for User A because it is valid purchase. How can we restrict before User B initiate the purchase? reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74397944/prevent-same-apple-account-in-auto-renewal-in-app-purchase