# Prevent same apple account in auto renewal in app purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have implemented auto-renewal subscription in app purchase in my app, but I am stuck in 1 case scenario.

User can sign up into app after successfully in-app purchase done. App is offer 2 plans Yearly & Monthly.

Let's suppose abc@apple.com in there as apple ID in device settings.

*Scenario*:

- User A gets the subscription with his app credentials and his Apple ID.
- User B uses User A's device and signup with User B app credentials but uses User A's Apple ID to buy a subscription.

Currently, it allows that User B to purchase this item but it says that there is a subscription with this user and asks for a permission to modify this subscription.

My question is how to prevent User B to modify User A's subscription? I could not find any solution before the receipt creation. I do not want to allow User B that modifies User A's subscription. I want to inform User B about using different Apple ID to continue to buy a subscription.

**How can I restrict user B before he initiate the purchase?**

**My Try**

I try to compare original transactionID, but it is after the purchase initiated & this will restrict the user B to sign up via backend server. But as it is valid purchase so server is update its plan if User B choose other plan than user A chosen before.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't mind with closing vote but can you please justify or give some path / explanantion? which is very helpful to me. Thank you